# Adding entries from python dictionary based on key

Tags: python, dictionary

If I have a Python dictionary such as

```
my_dict = {1:4, 2: 9, 3: 17, 4: 27, 5: 51, 6: 129, 7: 285, 8: 533}
```

how can I iterate through it to produce a count based on keys in the following way:

If my key is smallest i.e. 1, then return 4/sum(values) [I know how to compute this].

If my key is not smallest, then return sum(values corresponding to previous keys)/sum(values); so for example, for key 2, we would return 4+9/1055.

Thanks for any insights!

Comment: The point behind keys to be verbal tags and not numeric indexes, which you have lists and tuples for. It's highly inefficient to parse dictionary keys into integers - there are better data structures in Python for this.

Comment: You can iterate through keys by doing `for key in my_dict:` i.e. a simple for loop. Other than that, note that dictionaries are not sorted, so 'previous keys' is not well-defined.

Comment: To expand a bit on what @dmitryro said: a dictionary might not be the best way to represent your data.  For one thing, dictionaries have no specified order, so it can be tricky to determine what the 'previous' and 'next' elements are.  It's probably easier to use two lists, one for keys and one for values.  The keys list can be kept in sorted order.  (It's unclear from your sample data whether the values list can also be sorted.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
count_to_key = {
  k: sum(vi for ki, vi in my_dict.items()
              if ki <= k) / sum(my_dict.values())
                for k in my_dict.keys()}
```

Comment: >>> count_to_key[1] == 4/sum(my_dict.values()) True    >>> count_to_key[2] == (4 + 9)/sum(my_dict.values()) True

Comment: oh that makes sense, the `4+9/1055` in the OP confused me because of the lack of brackets, nevermind then.

Comment: PEP 20 line 2: Explicit is better than implicit :)

Comment: Thank you, this is perfect.

Comment: What kind of notation are you using / where can I learn more about this implementation?

Comment: Ah, iterating over key-value pairs. Thanks.

Comment: Yup, the only gotcha is that ki and vi are a layer down... I broke PEP 20.5: flat is better than nested :O